# Adding NSString to NSMutableString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to add multiple `NSStrings` yo an `NSMutableString` to construct a list of strings.

This is my code in a method that takes an `NSDictionary` and grabs the value out of it - it then stores it in an `NSString`, From there I append the string to the `NSMutableString`. When running this method for the first time it works. However, when I call the method again, it replaces the last string that was in the `NSMutableString`.

Here is the code:

```
NSString *userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", parameters[@"userId"]];
self.alluserIds = [NSMutableString string];


[self.alluserIds appendString:userId];
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

self.alluserIds is declared `strong`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
self.alluserIds = [NSMutableString string];
```

is creating a new mutable string. It should be done once, before you want to use the mutable string, and not done again until you want to restart (because recreating the mutable string destroys the old instance you had).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It seems I'm half asleep here. Thanks, this was obviously the issue. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is happened because you call:

```
self.alluserIds = [NSMutableString string];
```

This create new string and assign it to self.alluserIds. You should call it just once in for example init method or viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize with the string you are using and it should be a single initialization your code should look like below.

```
NSString *userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", parameters[@"userId"]];
if(!self.alluseIds)
    self.alluserIds = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:userId]; //ONLY Initialization
else
    [self.alluserIds appendString:userId];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data-structure, but if you might have all userids in an array you could join them together with `componentsJoinedByString:`:

```
NSArray *pathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"here", @"be", @"dragons", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",[pathArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);
```

Comment: Has to be in an NSDictionary. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mutable strings(and mutable collections too) except cases you really need it: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsstring.html (When To Use Mutable Strings) You have to use them when you want to make a lot of operations. Immutable collections are slower because you create new instance when append another string.

How to do this with `NSString`:

```
self.alluserIds = [self.alluserIds stringByAppendingString: userId];
```